# HTML5 fontsize resize on browser size javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hi I'm trying to resize my fontsize dynamically. base on my browser size.

I already have the following CSS, HTML and I'm trying to add something into my javascript

CSS

```
#firstPosition
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}

.textSize
{
    font-size: 150%;
    color: black;
}
```

HTML5

```
<div id="firstPosition">
    <p class="textSize">Hello</p>
</div>
```

My Positioning is absolute, so it will keep remaining at the center of my screen even if i  do a resize of my browser. but my text does not resize.

Any advice?

thanks.

SOLVED!

used

font-size: 1.2vw; instead

Comment: Where's the JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to use javascript to alter my height. But I've not been able to do so thus I've not add any javascript in

Comment: Height of the parent div or height of the font? You have given #firstPosition a fixed width and height, You want to resize the font while maintaining the size of the div?

Comment: Actually I want to resize everything according to my screen, that includes the height of the parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize according to the screen width (example)

```css
#firstPosition
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%; /** resize **/
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
}

.textSize
{
    font-size: 3vw; /** resize **/
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="firstPosition">
    <p class="textSize">Hello</p>
</div>
```

ALTERNATIVE JQUERY SOLUTION

```js
$( window ).resize(function() {
var ratio = $('#firstPosition').width() / 400;
$('.textSize').css({
  '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + ratio + ')',
  '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + ratio + ')',
  '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + ratio + ')',
  '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + ratio + ')',
  'transform'         : 'scale(' + ratio + ')',
  'transform-origin'  : '50% 50%'
});
});
```

```css
#firstPosition
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
}

.textSize {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstPosition">
    <p class="textSize">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i used font-size: 2vw;

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this meta tag in your html head

```
<head>
<title>Title</title>
....
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
....
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

use media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) { body { font-size:12px; }}
```

Here, when browser size becomes at least 640 or below, font size will be 12px.

You need to adjust min-width and CSS selector as per your requirement.

Note that you can have multiple media queries for different sizes.

Comment: Hi, it certainly did change my fontsize, however even though my current with is 1920, it still changes, may I know if I am doing it correct?